# How to add Azure VM (Windows) extensions using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am struggling with Installing/ Adding Azure VM extension on Windows hosts. Research on the internet pointed me to Azure_rm_deployment module but so far I have not been able to get it working.

Below is the example of my playbook

```
    - name: Install Anti-Malware
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      vars:
        sec: 'YK/xxxxxxxxxx/JnCsPTj4kRdsWblc='
      tasks:
      - name: Create Azure clear
        azure_rm_deployment:
        state: present
        subscription_id: 'b1514ce2-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx'
        client_id: 'xxxxxxx-cae7-45a3-xxxxxx-9b37bce64746'
        secret: '{{ sec }}'
        tenant: "78e60c0f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-63fe13a30962"
        location: 'uk west'
        resource_group_name: 'AnsibleRG'
        template_link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/octopus-deploy-tentacle-windows/azuredeploy.json
  #template: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/playbooks/OctopusDeployTentacle.json') | from_json }}"

        parameters:
          vmAdminUserName:
            value: adminUser
          vmAdminPassword:
            value: mYpAss
          vmDnsName:
            value: WinVM01
          tentacleOctopusServerUrl:
            value: https://octopus.example.com
          tentacleCommunicationMode:
            value: Listen
          tentacleApiKey:
            value: XXX-ABC-DDE-DDJD-GGGJ
          tentacleRoles:
            value: web
          tentacleEnvironments:
            value: Test
          tentaclePort:
            value: 10933
```

I have tried increasing the timeout by using 
        ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec
        ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec

But no luck so far.

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Rfd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change host to localhost, this is supposed to run on the localhost, well most likely scenario.

Comment: Thanks that helped I am able to make progress. However now getting a different error. When I run the modified playbook (updated original one above) I get                                              
"failed_deployment_operations": [], "msg": "Deployment failed with status code: 400 and message: Deployment template parse failed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 7, position 1.'."}. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you template link is wrong, you are supposed to link to a raw file, not web page with the file. this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/octopus-deploy-tentacle-windows/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it helped. Have been able to make some progress however now getting a different error with the updated playbook above                
            
**"Deployment failed with status code: 400 and message: The template deployment 'ansible-arm' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'c73feca6-ae2d-4c10-83a0-16be06819f5a'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."**      I get same error with other extensions as well. Any idea what am I doing wrong now?

Comment: well, this is a completely different question. I suggest you accept this answer and start a new question (post your template and your error, preferably the real error) and ping me with the url

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I have posted a new question [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683446/unable-to-add-extension-to-use-azure-vm-extensions-using-ansible).