# Unable to add extension to use Azure VM extensions using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to add Azure VM extension to already existing VM. Below is a sample playbook I am using to try and install Octopus Deploy Azure extension

```
  - name: Install Octopus deploy tentacle 
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      vars:
        sec: 'YK/xxxxxxxxxx/JnCsPTj4kRdsWblc='
      tasks:
      - name: Create Azure clear
        azure_rm_deployment:
        state: present
        subscription_id: 'b1514ce2-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx'
        client_id: 'xxxxxxx-cae7-45a3-xxxxxx-9b37bce64746'
        secret: '{{ sec }}'
        tenant: "78e60c0f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-63fe13a30962"
        location: 'uk west'
        resource_group_name: 'AnsibleRG'
        template_link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/octopus-deploy-tentacle-windows/azuredeploy.json
  #template: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/ansible/playbooks/OctopusDeployTentacle.json') | from_json }}"

        parameters:
          vmAdminUserName:
            value: adminUser
          vmAdminPassword:
            value: mYpAss
          vmDnsName:
            value: WinVM01
          tentacleOctopusServerUrl:
            value: https://octopus.example.com
          tentacleCommunicationMode:
            value: Listen
          tentacleApiKey:
            value: XXX-ABC-DDE-DDJD-GGGJ
          tentacleRoles:
            value: web
          tentacleEnvironments:
            value: Test
          tentaclePort:
            value: 10933
```

When I run the playbook I get error

> "Deployment failed with status code: 400 and message: The template deployment 'ansible-arm' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'c73feca6-ae2d-4c10-83a0-16be06819f5a'. See inner errors for details. Please see aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."

I have tried couple of other extensions as well but keep getting the same error. 
Can someone please guide me how can I resolve this?

Bellow is little more details of error I am getting

**After running playbook with -vvvv**

```
    Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/azure/azure_rm_deployment.py
    <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
    <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
    <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842="` echo /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842 `" ) && sleep 0'
    <127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpQY52K0 TO /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842/azure_rm_deployment.py
    <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842/ /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842/azure_rm_deployment.py && sleep 0'
    <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842/azure_rm_deployment.py; rm -rf "/home/rafid/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518117111.96-175732666939842/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
    The full traceback is:
      File "/tmp/ansible_PZzWZG/ansible_module_azure_rm_deployment.py", line 509, in deploy_template
        deploy_parameter)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/resource/resources/v2017_05_10/operations/deployments_operations.py", line 282, in create_or_update
        get_long_running_status, long_running_operation_timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/msrestazure/azure_operation.py", line 350, in __init__
        raise CloudError(self._response)

    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
        "changed": false,
        "failed_deployment_operations": [],
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "ad_user": null,
                "append_tags": true,
                "cli_default_profile": null,
                "client_id": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "cloud_environment": null,
                "deployment_mode": "incremental",
                "deployment_name": "ansible-arm",
                "location": "uk west",
                "parameters": {
                    "tentacleApiKey": {
                        "value": "XXX-ABC-DDE-DDJD-GGGJ"
                    },
                    "tentacleCommunicationMode": {
                        "value": "Listen"
                    },
                    "tentacleEnvironments": {
                        "value": "Test"
                    },
                    "tentacleOctopusServerUrl": {
                        "value": "https://octopus.example.com"
                    },
                    "tentaclePort": {
                        "value": 10933
                    },
                    "tentacleRoles": {
                        "value": "web"
                    },
                    "vmAdminPassword": {
                        "value": "mYpAss"
                    },
                    "vmAdminUserName": {
                        "value": "adminUser"
                    },
                    "vmDnsName": {
                        "value": "WinVM01"
                    }
                },
                "parameters_link": null,
                "password": null,
                "profile": null,
                "resource_group_name": "AnsibleRG",
                "secret": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "state": "present",
                "subscription_id": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "tags": null,
                "template": null,
                "template_link": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/octopus-deploy-tentacle-windows/azuredeploy.json",
                "tenant": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                "wait_for_deployment_completion": true,
                "wait_for_deployment_polling_period": 10
            }
        },
        "msg": "Deployment failed with status code: 400 and message: The template deployment 'ansible-arm' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '1bf65caf-3b8c-4521-8370-65bae816404b'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details."
    }
```

**Below is what I see in Azure Portal Activity log**

```
{
    "authorization": {
        "action": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write",
        "scope": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/AnsibleRG/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ansible-arm"
    },
    "caller": "2c02c92d-c9b8-4fc2-8140-40f8ba2052a5",
    "channels": "Operation",
    "claims": {
        "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/78e60c0f-344b-405f-8c9a-63fe13a30962/",
        "iat": "1518116812",
        "nbf": "1518116812",
        "exp": "1518120712",
        "aio": "Y2NgYDjveebWbh3lRJuJone1i7fPAwA=",
        "appid": "004bc69c-cae7-45a3-8bed-9b37bce64746",
        "appidacr": "1",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider": "https://sts.windows.net/78e60c0f-344b-405f-8c9a-63fe13a30962/",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier": "2c02c92d-c9b8-4fc2-8140-40f8ba2052a5",
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "2c02c92d-c9b8-4fc2-8140-40f8ba2052a5",
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid": "78e60c0f-344b-405f-8c9a-63fe13a30962",
        "uti": "xhHR-2Xepke_G1gchNgPAA",
        "ver": "1.0"
    },
    "correlationId": "1bf65caf-3b8c-4521-8370-65bae816404b",
    "description": "",
    "eventDataId": "9c32a95d-ed19-4b1f-9826-d68e45742629",
    "eventName": {
        "value": "EndRequest",
        "localizedValue": "End request"
    },
    "category": {
        "value": "Administrative",
        "localizedValue": "Administrative"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-02-08T19:11:54.0105833Z",
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/AnsibleRG/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ansible-arm/events/9c32a95d-ed19-4b1f-9826-d68e45742629/ticks/636537139140105833",
    "level": "Error",
    "operationId": "1bf65caf-3b8c-4521-8370-65bae816404b",
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write"
    },
    "resourceGroupName": "AnsibleRG",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Resources",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft Resources"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
    },
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/AnsibleRG/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/ansible-arm",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "BadRequest",
        "localizedValue": "Bad Request (HTTP Status Code: 400)"
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2018-02-08T19:12:10.4497444Z",
    "subscriptionId": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
    "properties": {
        "statusCode": "BadRequest",
        "serviceRequestId": null,
        "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"InvalidTemplateDeployment\",\"message\":\"The template deployment 'ansible-arm' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '1bf65caf-3b8c-4521-8370-65bae816404b'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"InvalidDomainNameLabel\",\"message\":\"The domain name label WinVM01 is invalid. It must conform to the following regular expression: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$.\",\"details\":[]}]}}"
    },
    "relatedEvents": []
}
```

Thanks, 
Rfd

Comment: i dont remember if it helps, can you start playbook with -vvvv and paste real error into the question? if it doesnt use: `get-azurermlog -correlationid c73feca6-ae2d-4c10-83a0-16be06819f5a` to get the error. or go to the portal, open up "monitor" blade, activity and search for the deployment validation error and lookup the real cause in the json output and paste it here

Comment: Just updated the question with error details

Comment: you should probably remove all the extra data, just leave the `'properties`' node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is:

```
The domain name label WinVM01 is invalid. It must conform to the following regular expression: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$
```

basically, no capital letters

Comment: Thanks that helped. However now when I run the playbook it creates a new VM, I want to attach extension to existing VM. How can I do that?

Comment: i would modify this template, else its really hard to make it work, you really need only 1 resource in the template (extensión) if you want to add extensión to a vm

Comment: but generally in this case you need the `vmname` variable to match your vm name

Comment: It seems like using azure-quickstart-templates for Octopus Deploy is not a way to add extensions to existing VMs as it spins up a new machine. I am unable to find a way to add Azure extensions to existing machine. I am primarily interested in adding Antimalware extension to running machines. Perhaps its better if i log a separate question for this.